# Azure Powershell command unable to store bacpac file in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

### Background

I am trying to setup a powershell script to create a .bacpac file and store it in Azure's blob storage. I'm using the *Get-AzureRmSqldatabaseExport* command and have pointed it towards my storage container.

The command runs, and from what I understand, will begin the process six hours after running the command.

### Problem

The problem is that after a couple minutes, I get an error message stating that the blob storage only has read rights instead of both read and write.

### Questions

How do I modify the powershell command to allow me to write to the storage container? Is it something that I have to do with the container itself? Am I using blobs incorrectly, and should use a different type of storage type?

### More Info

Command:

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName "rgnEverything" -ServerName "serverOne" -DatabaseName "databaseDev" -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" -StorageKey "storageKeyOne" -StorageUri "storageUriOne" -AdministratorLogin "adminlogin" -AdministratorLoginPassword (ConvertTo-Secu
reString "password" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

I am currently running this command via Azure Cloud Shell

This is what *Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus* returns right after running the command:

```
OperationStatusLink : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/e088f9f1-aeed-401e-b8db-8bac796c43cd/resourceGroups/SweetSpot/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sweetspotgolfshop/databases/SweetSpotDev/importExportOp
                      erationResults/9226c1e7-5e55-4d34-ba96-954b857c318c?api-version=2014-04-01-Preview
ErrorMessage        :
LastModifiedTime    : 3/16/2018 3:24:38 PM
QueuedTime          : 3/16/2018 3:24:35 PM
StatusMessage       : Running, Progress = 0%
Status              : InProgress
```

Error Message:

```
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus : BadRequest: The ImportExport operation with Request Id '9226c1e7-5e55-4d34-ba96-954b857c318c' failed due to 'Error encountered during the service operation.
        Blob https://cs2e088f9f1aeedx401exb8d.blob.core.windows.net/database-backup is not writeable.
                The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
                        The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink "https: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ImportExport.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus
```

Storage Uri:

```
-StorageUri "https://cs2e088f9f1aeedx401exb8d.blob.core.windows.net/database-backup"
```

Comment: Not enough information to answer. How do you start the process (code please)? How do you provide a storage key? is this is a SAS-signed access key to the storage? What you describe is not normal, I get databases exported within minutes after command is executed and I never seen such message before. So you are doing something strange.

Comment: @trailmax I've added the command using generic info. I provided the storage key by navigating the storage account and using the on efound in the Access keys section of the settings. I'm not sure what you mean by SAS-signed access key. Still trying to learn my way around Azure.

Comment: HM.. I've never run it from azure shell, always on local machine or in Azure Automation. Is blob name `https://cs2e088f9f1aeedx401exb8d.blob.core.windows.net/database-backup` really what you have put in as a destination? It does look like an auto-generated account for Azure Shell.

Comment: The string of characters before .blob are randomly generated, but the actual container name is database-backup. I grabbed the URL for it by right clicking the container, and going to the Container Properties. Once there, I copied the given URL

Comment: OK, something is wrong with that storage account then. How did you create it?

Comment: Azure > Create a resource > Searched for Blob > Storage account - blob, file, table, queue > Create > Entered info

Comment: Can you write to the account from storage explorer? Like create/delete new files there?

Comment: I was just able to upload a pdf to it

Comment: OK, how does your `-StorageUri "storageUriOne"` look in real command?

Comment: Added it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem that you specify container address as a target. You need to put full desired stored url of the file, not just container path.

So your `-StorageUri` parameter value should look like

```
https://mystorageName.blob.core.windows.net/databasebackup/MyDbName-2018-03-16.bacpac
```

Also you need to make sure that container already exist before you try to backup, it will not be created for you by the export.

Comment: Good stuff! glad that helped you